# Querying Realm in Flutter using DateTime

Tags: mongodb, flutter, dart, realm

I am using a schema that contains `DataTime` as one of the fields. When writing a query based on said field (named 'due') I keep getting a:

> RealmException Error code: 35 . Message: Invalid predicate: 'due >=
> 2022-12-29 17:20:25.830699': syntax error, unexpected number,
> expecting end of file"

I tried to look up the error code and could not find it. I have tried hard coding the date and that doesn't work either. I have written other predicates based on strings or ints and those seem to work. For some reason the DateTime is boofed.

Here is the query function:

```
RealmResults<Exercise> todoExercise() {
  DateTime date = DateTime.now();
  final results = realm.query<Exercise>('due >= $date');
  return results;
}
```

pubspec.yaml relevant contents:

> environment:   sdk: '>=2.18.5 <3.0.0'
>
> dependencies:   mongo_dart: ^0.8.2
>
> flutter:
> sdk: flutter
>
> cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2   realm: ^0.8.0+rc   intl: ^0.18.0

As mentioned above, I am trying to return a list of objects whose due date is equal to or greater than todays date. I have manually added due dates in late January so I am expecting 3 results. I keep getting the invalid predicate.

Comment: You didn't include your Realm model - it's a good idea to do that to help clarify the question. What is the `due` property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format of your DateTime string doesn't match the required format for the realm query language (see [realm docs on DateTime operators](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/realm-query-language/#date-operators)). Instead of doing the formatting yourself though, you can just run a parameterized query:

```
RealmResults<Exercise> todoExercise() {
  DateTime date = DateTime.now();
  final results = realm.query<Exercise>(r'due >= $0', [date]);
  return results;
}
```

Notice the "r" before the query string - that's required so that the dollar sign is treated as a normal character.